# call ajax with mootools

Tags: joomla, mootools

Hi everyone I call ajax with mootols and obtain this error, I looking for internet but dont find anything

this is my code to call ajax

```
 $$('.item-129 a').addEvent('click', function(event){
                event.stop();
                var req= new Request({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: '<?php echo JURI::root()?>index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6',
                    data: {'do': '1'},
                    onComplete: function(responseText){$('textos').set('html', responseText);}
                }).send();
            });
```

and this the error

```
TypeError: $("textos").set is not a function
anonymous()mootoo...ssed.js (línea 959) 

return self.apply(bind, args || arguments);
```

any idea!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means that either:

- the element is not found
- you don't use mootools 1.2+, hence no set method, unlikely given you use Request and not ajax
- jQuery has the $ or something else, which does not have the .set method

try first of all:

```
onComplete: function(){
    console.log($("textos"));
}
```

if this responds, see what it returns. if you use jquery, it will return the wrapped jquery function. if it's mootools, it will be an element.

if you have jquery, mootools will silently drop to `document.id` instead.

so. write as `document.id('textos').set('html', responseText)`

if with `document.id('textos')` you don't get an element either, it's not found.